# Why doesnt the clear button remove price from cart

Tags: javascript, html

I want remove the price from my cart using a clear button. I am able to remove the rows/products , but I am not sure why the price is not changing. Please check out [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPbBmd?editors=101).

```
function removecart() {
    salesTotal = 0;
    var table = document.getElementById("shoppingCart");
    for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
        table.deleteRow(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: you are not updating the id=total div with value 0, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides changing your `salesTotal` variable to zero, you need to update the display representation accordingly.
You could easily add this:

```
function removecart() {
   salesTotal = 0;
   var table = document.getElementById("shoppingCart");
   for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
       table.deleteRow(i);
   }
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "<strong>Sale Price</strong>: $" + salesTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

But you could also implement another function to automate this functionality and avoid writing repeatidly the same code within your js:

```
function changeTotal(newTotal){
    salesTotal = newTotal;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "<strong>Sale Price</strong>: $" + salesTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I see using the innerHTML again . I thought that using `salestotal=0` would have the same effect.

Comment: By setting the `innerHTML` property you unfortunately do not establish a direct binding to the variable. MVC frameworks like AngularJS do enable such a procedure but they come with a lot of overhead, so a simple function like the one mentioned above should be your choice at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your price isn't changing because you aren't changing it. Add to the function:

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = salesTotal;
```

Comment: Can't you just delete the answer instead of editing it into something that doesn't make any sense...?

Answer (score 0):

The clear button does remove the price from the cart, but it doesn't show it because you never wrote the code to update it.

```
function removecart() {
   salesTotal = 0;
   var table = document.getElementById("shoppingCart");
   for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
   {
       table.deleteRow(i);
   }
       document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "<strong>Sale Price</strong>: $" +     salesTotal.toFixed(2);
   }
```

should work